# solve this error 404:The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Tags: spring, spring-tool-suite

i'm getting this error 404:while running the project on server.

This is for the sts 3.7.3 release with maven m2.i changed the path in pom.xml

pom.xml:

```
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
  <outputDirectory>WebContent/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

 <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
           <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory> 
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this problem many times.

The solution I am currently using is whether the `webapp` (or the folder where you kept the views like jsp) is under deployment assembly.

Try this:

Right click on the project > `Build Path` > `Configure Build path` > `Deployment Assembly` > `Add`(right hand side) > `Folder` > (add your jsp folder, by default it is `src/main/webapp`)

Note: If you have another folder named `pages` under `webapp` which have the jsp files, say like  `src/main/webapp/pages`, then you have to include that too in the build path.